# jsonpath expression for value match

Tags: python, json, search, xpath, jsonpath

Hi I have this test data

```
data = [
  {
      "company" : "abc",
      "CEO" : "john"
  },
  {
      "company" : "xyz",
      "CEO" : "ron"
  }
]
```

I want to query data by "ron", and want to get

```
  {
      "company" : "xyz",
      "CEO" : "ron"
  }
```

I know in xpath I could write an expression  *//*[*="ron"]*  to get this, but not able to come up with similar jsonpath expression. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one and let me know whether it's the exactly result you want to get:

```
$.[?(@.CEO=="ron")]
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson. Yes this gives the result I want, but when I am building the query I don't know that "ron" is a CEO, so the query shouldn't refer to any attribute in data, is should just search by the value.


   `$.[?(@.*=="ron")]`    # invalid expression but something like this, just a wild card instead of referring to attribute

Answer (score 1):

There are differences in the various JSONPath implementations. The expression `$[?("ron" in @.*)]` should give you what you want if using the [Jayway](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) (Java) implementation. Test [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com). Put the array without the `data =` in the input box.

Because the expression is indeterminate, it will always return a list i.e.

```
[
  {
    "company" : "xyz",
    "CEO" : "ron"
  }
]
```